# Protecting Assets in Cordova/Phonegap Application

Tags: android, cordova, video, encryption

I am working on a cordova android application which will display images and videos.I have the images and videos in the assets folder.I want to protect my resources.I don't want anyone to copy the resources.I have googled for the same and didn't get any proper solution.How to protect files in assets?

Is there any way to encrypt and store videos in assets folder and decrypt it during run time?

My video files will be maximum of 10 MB each file and there are 50 videos in the whole application.

Comment: You didn't get a solution, because there isn't one. The best you can do is only obfuscation.

Comment: @ArtjomB.  Can videos be obfuscated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this with DRM - it won't stop someone copying the video files, but as they are encrypted they will not be able to play them back without the correct key.

The process is roughly:

- your content is encrypted before it is streamed or downloaded
- when the user wants to playback the content the app must request a key for the content from owner of the content or the 'rights authority' (a service which handles keys for content)
- The DRM system on the device will securely encrypt the content and play it back using the key it obtained. The video will not be stored in clear format at any point.

Native Android DRM is explained here:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html

To use this with cordova I think you will have to create a Native plugin - I could not see any cordova DRM API. Alternatively, if you are able to stream the content using the new MPEG DASH format, then you could use a HTML5 video player which supports DRM, such as BitDASH (https://www.dash-player.com).

You need to be aware that all DRM and encryption systems are really just hurdles that make it harder to copy content - at the end of the day if you have a very high quality display and a very high quality camera to record the display, then no DRM protection will save you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer have helped me a lot. But still i am struggling with DRM. :-(